# Swift: Append multiple UnsafeMutablePointers to one

Tags: swift

In swift when we want to append multiple arrays to one we just:

```
let resultArray=arr1+arr2+...+arrN
```

Is there is a way to do such operation with multiple UnsafeMutablePointers.

I created next struct:

```
struct ArrayStruct<T> where T: Equatable {

    public private(set) var count: Int

    public private(set) var pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>

    public var hasNegativeNumbers: Bool = false

    init(_count: Int, initialValue: T?) {
        self.count = _count

        self.pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.allocate(capacity: _count)
        if initialValue != nil {
            self.pointer.initialize(to: initialValue!, count: self.count)
        }
    }

    mutating func addValue(at index: Int, value: T) {
        if value < 0 {
            self.hasNegativeNumbers = true
        }
        self.pointer.advanced(by: index).pointee = value
    }
```

Is there is a way to write function that will append pointer values to another pointer values?

Comment: Why using an unsafe concept instead of a safe one, like an array?

Comment: I have huge arrays and complex algorithm that is using huge memory and CPU. I have to reduce them.  I found this https://tech.vinelab.com/playing-with-swift-performance-test-646f2b385a33 link and I have to transform arrays to pointers

Comment: Arrays use pointers for storage behind the scenes, so from this point both approaches are equivalent. What are the exact limitations of arrays that you run into and made you want to switch to unsafe pointers?

Comment: E.g. I have matrixes 430x430 on which I perform Cartesian multiplication. When I used regular arrays that action drain my memory, however after conversation to above link pointers method  it decreased almost to 50%.

Comment: You mentioned in the question that you want to do concatenation of multiple  pointers, well in respect to this the array buffer increase algorithms are quite optimized so you'd get better results with arrays. I'm not saying that arrays are better than raw pointers in all cases, but in the case of concatenation operations the arrays work quite well, and use well tested code.

Comment: BTW, your struct will likely crash the app if asked to add more values that initially allocated. In order to address this you have to grow the allocated buffer when it gets full, and again arrays are top-notch for this task. Unless you work with fixed size arrays, in which case you might get better results with an approach like your, however you'n need to write some code for this, and you need to throughly test it afterwards since when using unsafe pointers is easy to shot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @Cristik Thanks for the feedback. I have those functions below posted code :)

Comment: Note that your option to pass `nil` for `initialValue` means that the memory you're pointing to could either be uninitialised or initialised, but then you perform assignment later in `addValue(at:value:)`, which requires initialised memory if `T` is non-trivial, and is *undefined behaviour* if it's uninitialised. I would advise always initialising the memory in `init(_count:initialValue:)`. Also note that you're not deallocating or deinitialising the memory anywhere, so you'll get memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of the question, I'm providing an answer to your query, with the strong recommendation to be careful when directly manipulating pointers, as you can easily run into all kind of issues (buffer overflows, vulnerabilities, etc). Also I would recommend some optimizations to your current code: `Collection` conformance, better semantics for method names, usage of `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` which is better for array-like operations, to name a few.

Now, getting to the chase, what you need when concatenating two arrays is to allocate a new buffer big enough to hold the contents of the two concatenated ones, and them copy the bytes from the two other ones.

Adding a new method to `ArrayStruct` will help you with that:

```
mutating func append(contentsOf other: ArrayStruct<T>) {
    // allocate memory to hold both buffers
    let newPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.allocate(capacity: count + other.count)

    // copy the first buffer
    newPtr.initialize(from: pointer, count: count)

    // copy the second buffer
    newPtr.advanced(by: count).initialize(from: other.pointer, count: other.count)

    // update the internal state
    pointer = newPtr
    count += other.count
}
```

followed by a short overload of the `+` function:

```
func +<T>(lhs: ArrayStruct<T>, rhs: ArrayStruct<T>) -> ArrayStruct<T> {
    var result = lhs
    result.append(contentsOf: rhs)
    return result
}
```

Now you have all the premises to concatenate as many `ArrayStruct` instances as you need. Note that this is a rough approach, a better one might reallocate the first pointer at the same location so you'd only have to copy the second set of bytes.

I'm reiterating again, just make sure that all operations on those unsafe pointers are guarded by checks that make sure you don't write to unexpected memory addresses.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I will try you solution and will mark it as accepted as soon as possible